# How to set Cadence test workflow id?

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm following https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/go-client/workflow-testing/#setup and seeing errors with `Activity error. {"WorkflowID": "default-test-workflow-id"`.

How do I go about setting the `WorkflowID` (eg so that it contains the test name)? I'm using Go.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported directly to set a workflowID. we recently realized it and are actively working on this.

At the mean time, if you have to test with workflowID, a workaround is to use

```
ReplayWorkflowExecution(ctx context.Context, service workflowserviceclient.Interface, logger *zap.Logger, domain string, execution workflow.Execution) error
```

But you have to mock the service interface for fetching history.

See https://github.com/uber-go/cadence-client/blob/b31c3bbfb06a1f96c6ad911a48237cfbc4f9a565/worker/worker.go#L166

I will update this thread when this feature is implemented.